# Observe value of input component

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple component that is a `input` element via the `tagName`.

So far no problem. Now I would like to observe the value attribute of the input. Anytime the input is changed I would like to fire an observer.

Why does this not work?

A JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ma0qd4/1/).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{my-input}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-input">
</script>

var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBinding: ['value'],
    onChange: Ember.observer('value', function() {
        console.log('change');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** This solution applies to the version of ember that is used by the OP (ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js) , in future versions the concept remains the same only the syntax changes a bit.

*(Example for version 1.13.6 https://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuhavokubi/edit?html,js,output , code posted at the very end)*

The issues with the original code are the following,

1.The property for binding the attribute is `attributeBindings`

2.The `Ember.observer` works just fine in future versions, but does not seem to work within the component in this one (ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js)

3.Added alternative observer function using `observes`

4.Added function to handle dom value change and notify ember property

**Examples,**

**for version ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js** *(http://jsfiddle.net/3vre965u/)*

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{my-input}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-input">
    the value:{{value}}<br/><button {{action "changeTheValue"}}>change value</button>
    <button {{action "displayTheValues"}}>display values</button>
</script>
```

**js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBindings: ['value'],
    changeTheValue:function(){
        this.set('value',Date.now());
    },
    displayTheValues:function(){
        alert("ember value:\n"+this.get("value")+"\nDOM value:\n"+this.$().val());
    },
    //catches dom event
    //fires only when focused lost
    change:function(event){
        this.set("value",event.target.value);
    },
    //catches dom event
    keyUp:function(event){
        this.set("value",event.target.value);
    },
    //works like this in future versions, does not work in current version
    onChange: Ember.observer('value', function() {
        console.log('change');
    }),
    //alternative observer that works fine in current version
    onChange2: function(){
        console.log('change2');
    }.observes('value')
});
```

---

**for version 1.13.6** *(https://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuhavokubi/edit?html,js,output )*

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{my-input viewName="test"}}
    <br/>
    the value:{{view.test.value}}<br/><button {{action "changeTheValue" target="view.test"}}>change value</button>
    <button {{action "displayTheValues" target="view.test"}}>display values</button>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/my-input">
</script>
```

**js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    attributeBindings: ['value'],
  actions:{
   changeTheValue:function(){
        this.set('value',Date.now());
    },
    displayTheValues:function(){
        alert("ember value:\n"+this.get("value")+"\nDOM value:\n"+this.$().val());
    } 
  },
    //catches dom event
    //fires only when focused lost
    change:function(event){
        this.set("value",event.target.value);
    },
    //catches dom event
    keyUp:function(event){
        this.set("value",event.target.value);
    },
    onChange: Ember.observer('value', function() {
        console.log('change');
    }),
    //alternative observer
    onChange2: function(){
        console.log('change2');
    }.observes('value')
});
```